# In ASCIIDOC, Is there a variable to access the current section number?

Tags: asciidoc

What I am trying to do:

```
== Section

=== Subsection

.Note {section}.{subsection}.{note counter}
[NOTE]
...
```

Is this possible automatically?

Comment: as far as I know this is not possible automatically, you can implement your own "note counter" with a counter though, see https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/counters/.

Answer (score 0):

```
= Chapter Title
:sectnums:
:section-refsig:

== Section Title

[#secid]
=== Subsection Title

The number of the section identified `secid` is xref:secid[xrefstyle=short].
```

The `:sectnums:` is needed to number the sections.
With the `:section-refsig:` you can specify the prefix that stands in front of the reference in case of a section. When you want to use only the number then it is empty as in the example above.

After this you can identify your section, or rely  on Ascidoc auto identifiers for sections and use an `xref`. The `xrefstyle` specifies the reference style. In case of `short` it is the prefix (empty in this case) and the number.

I could not find how to number notes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What/how do you mean to "After this you can identify your section"? I don't want to create a link, I just want to use the current section number as variable? Something like `{sectid}`, without the reference?

Comment: I meant that you could use `[#secid]` to give a name to your section and use the name in the reference.

I do not know if you can use the number simply and not as a reference.

Suppose you are desperate and want more control over counters and numbers. In that case, you can use the Jamal preprocessor I developed for AsciiDoc, Markdown, JavaDoc, etc. meet their limit.

Jamal is well integrated with AsciiDoc, perhaps the easiest to use integration, and available from my GitHub repository at https://github.com/verhas/jamal

Comment: Thank you, that is definitely worth a look. I already thought in an own pre oder post processor already, too.

Comment: Be very careful with copy pasting if you use this method. The links are not dynamic so you could be pointing to the wrong subsection if you do not update the `sectid`!

Comment: ‘secid’ in the example above is the name of the section. It could be ‘abrakadabra’ and it will always dynamically refer to the section you named ‘secid’ (or ‘abrakadabra’).